# Android AdMob errors

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to put some ads in my application, but I can't, haha. 
I added this in the Gradle:

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0' and
```

I have an error saying :

```
   Failed to find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
```

Can anyone help? This is the first time I've used it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you had Google Repository package installed from Android SDK Manager:

Go Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools Tab: And doublecheck Google Repository is installed and updated to last version.

Comment: I just checked and updated it. Still the same error. Maybe there is something I should install but i don't know ??